# React Native iOS Universal Links - Error cannot fetch app site association

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

Why am I getting this error?

[image]

Universal linking works fine and opens the app:

- When tapping on a result link on Chrome/Safari.
- Via Message app and other social media apps.

But when I try to validate it through `https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool`, it shows an error (above).

Also validated on `https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator` and everything was passed.

**Domain link**: https://www.urban.com.au

**Json format**:

```json
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "<Team ID>.<Bundle ID>",
                "paths": [
                    "/path_1/*",
                    "/path_2/*",
                ],
                "appIDs": [
                    "<Team ID>.<Bundle ID>"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/path_1/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/path_2/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any idea on what the issue might be?

Browser version: Chrome 88.0.4324.192